# C++ nullptr detection

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following code. I don't understand why the first conditional gets invoked in B.GetNum(). How can I ensure when a gets deleted in main that my class B does not try to use the deleted variable?

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int num) : m_num(num) {}
    int GetNum() { return m_num; }

private:
    int m_num;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A* a_) : a(a_) {}
    int GetNum()
    {
        if (a != nullptr)
        {
            return a->GetNum(); // Why does this branch get called?
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

private:
    A* a;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A* a = new A(5);
    B b = B(a);
    delete a;
    a = nullptr;

    int result = b.GetNum();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem you are having is you copy the pointer when you create `b` in `main()`.  When you change `a` in `main()` it has no effect on pointer stored in `b`.

This is a perfect use case for a [std::weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr).  You can have `B` take a `weak_ptr` and then in `GetNum` you can check if the pointer still exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different `a`. The statement `a = nullptr;` affects only the pointer inside main. The pointer inside `b` is a copy and contains the old value (now invalid).

Using it in `GetNum()` leads to undefined behavior, and *anything* can happen.

Answer (score 1):

Because you copied `A*` value into you class - it is never changed, but when you deleted original allocated value, you pointer point to a garbage location.